# How to automatically disable EVF when LCD is pulled out on FujiFilm X-T20?

Tags: fujifilm, fujifilm-x-t20

My X-T20 switches to EVF when the LCD it tilted out. I know some cameras automatically disable the EVF when the LCD is pulled out, since the only reason to pull the LCD out is to use it. How can I set my camera to automatically disable EVF when the LCD is pulled out?

Answer (score 1):

The Fujifilm X-T20 does not have that feature. There is no way to add because the camera has no idea that the LCD is pulled out. On those with that feature, there is usually a  sensor or mechanical switch that gets pushed in when the LCD is flush against the body which enables the camera to behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a view mode button somewhere on the camera, on the x-t1/2 its on the side of the viewfinder.  Unsure if it has a mode for your specific need, but thats propably your best bet.

Comment: That just rotates among EVF, LCD, EVF/eye, EVF+LCD/eye. It doesn't automatically disable EVF or eye detection when the LCD is pulled out.